# Can both a table and indexed view be columnstore?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore

I have a data warehouse fact table with millions of records and it is a clustered columnstore table. I want to have an Indexed View of the table which casts numeric values of a Text column to numbers and text values of the same column to blanks, for faster performance.

If I create the View as a clustered Index View, will the View's data also be stored in columnstore format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before even reading my answer you should read [this](http://www.nikoport.com/2016/10/10/columnstore-indexes-part-87-indexed-views/) excellent post by Niko Neugebauer *the* dude to go for columnstore indexes in SQL Server.

To my answer:

Yes you can create a clustered columnstore index in a view in SQL Server. My recommendation would be to test your view first and then decide if you need a new index or the columnstore index from the underlying table is satisfying your conditions.